# Update table with a union subselect

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi everybody and thanks in advance,

I'm trying to execute this update in MsAccess

`UPDATE CLIENTES SET NOMBRE = 'CLIENTE VACIO' WHERE CODIGO IN
(select CODIGO from clientes wherE NOMBRE =''
UNION select CODIGO from clientes wherE NOMBRE IS NULL);`

but I get a message saying something like "operation not allowed in a subqwery".

How can I turn this update into MsAccess sql?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead, don't use `union` use `or`:

```
UPDATE CLIENTES
    SET NOMBRE = 'CLIENTE VACIO'
    WHERE CODIGO IN (select CODIGO
                     from clientes
                     where NOMBRE = '' or
                           NOMBRE is NULL
                    );
```

This is clearer and would have better performance anyway (`UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicate values).

Comment: Sure Gordon, how couldn't I see that? Thanks for your help, and any way, do you now what's the correct syntax for my update? Thanks a lot!